# Micorsoft.Web.Administration Error

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I'm using Micorsoft.Web.Administration to access ServerManager.Sites and sometime i get this exception when trying to access the same host

System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024894
  Message=Filename: \?\40.xxx.xxx.xxx
Error: Cannot read configuration file

```
Source=""
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.AppHostWritableAdminManager.GetAdminSection(String bstrSectionName, String bstrSectionPath)
       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration.GetSectionInternal(ConfigurationSection section, String sectionPath, String locationPath)
       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.get_SitesSection()
       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.get_Sites()
       at Connectivity_Matrix.Script.ServerScanner.Scan() in \\DESKTOP-B795PQL\Connectivity_Matrix\Connectivity_Matrix.Script\ServerScanner.cs:line 33
       at Connectivity_Matrix.Script.Program.Main(String[] args) in \\DESKTOP-B795PQL\Connectivity_Matrix\Connectivity_Matrix.Script\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Micorsoft.Web.Administration has many bugs and limitation such as:

- Cannot set credentials for ServerManager.OpenRemote()
- Cannot get all site sections as example system.servicemodel/client
- Many COM exceptions while trying access ServerManager properties

so i could simply remotly download the applicationHost.config then each site web.config and open them using linq to xml:

```
var configPath = $@"\\{serverIP}\c$\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config";
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "Domain");
wc.DownloadFile(configPath, "applicationHost.config");
var sitesXml = XElement.Load("applicationHost.config").Element("system.applicationHost").Element("sites").Elements("site");
//then get physical path attribute of each site and download it's web.config
```